# FireBase Realtime DB Not Inserting Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my register activity. It works before this point

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
        .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });`
```

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-RE1QuUWPg&ab_channel=CodeWithMazn

I followed that tutorial and also tried taking the first code snippet out with the example in tools>firebase>realtime db and no results. I also tried getReferenceFromUrl() and that didn't work either.

I'm building a sudoku vocabulary game and just looking to save users now. Later on I will want to query and find the top 10 scores. The user is timed with a stopwatch until they complete the game. Should I change to a sqlite datebase? It seems to be more function with less chances of a roadblock down the road.

Comment: I'm not able to post my build.gradle file since it says my post will be most code. FOH SOF

Comment: Is any of the toast messages displayed? If yes, which one? If not, is your onComplete ven triggered? What is the location of your database?

Comment: None of the toast messages were displaying. I have this assignment due in about 9 hours so I'm going to just use sqlite. The docs for firebase are complete trash